# Parsing integers, including a range, from an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I need to get symbols from string like this ("5, 15, 7-10")
and symbols until first comma need to write into the first string until second into the second string and symbols that separated dash need to write to the array with the recalculation of the value of the first to the last.

Comment: Deleting and [reposting your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294335/parsing-integers-including-a-range-from-an-nsstring) is not appreciated here. In the future, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use componentSeparatedByString:

```
NSString *list = @"5, 15, 7-10";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

That would return an array that looks like `@[@"5", @"15", @"7-10"];`

From what I understood of your question, that should work. You may want to refine your question though, as its a bit hard to figure out. If you do and what I did doesn't work id be happy to fix the solution.

Edit: The following code does what you want (I think):

```
NSString *list = @"5, 15, 7-10";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
NSMutableArray *expandedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString *s in listItems){
    NSRange found = [s rangeOfString:@"-"];
    if (found.location == 1) {
        NSArray *hyphenString = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        NSInteger first = [[hyphenString objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        NSInteger last = [[hyphenString objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        [expandedList addObject:@(first)];
        NSInteger trueDiff = (last - first) - 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < trueDiff){
            first = first + 1;
            [expandedList addObject:@(first)];
            i++;
        }
        [expandedList addObject:@(last)];

    } else {
        [expandedList addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[s intValue]]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", expandedList);
```

That will output:

```
2013-08-17 21:12:54.579 NumWork[693:303] (
    5,
    15,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
)
```

Comment: Thank u so much.

But I need to return two strings with 5 and 15 and array which contain the value from 7 to 10.

Comment: Is the 7-10 always going to be at the end of the string?

Comment: No, it may be everywhere

Comment: So when you see 7-10, you want it to print 7, 8, 9, 10?

Comment: An `NSScanner` might be a better way to do this.